# how to get google storage object name from having get_serving_url

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I use Google App Engine, python 2.7, to upload images.
The upload process works in 2 steps - the client first gets Google Cloud Storage upload url, and then POSTs multipart with image. The uploaded to GCS data is then posted to the upload handler. 
The upload handler, derived from blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler
gets info about images uploaded to GCS. get_file_infos being inherited, here is how I get my gcs_read_url

```
 upload_file_info= self.get_file_infos('file')[0]
 gs_object_name = upload_file_info.gs_object_name
 gs_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(gs_object_name)
 gcs_read_url = images.get_serving_url(gs_key)
```

I persist all these data in a datastore.

The problem is this. There is a serving url that works, the picture is shown in a browser. However, I get the gs_object_name from my datastore, look it up in the bucket, and it is missing. Since it is serving, it is there somewhere, and I am paying for its storage.

The question: is there a way to programmatically get the datastore object name from the serving url?

Comment: `gs_object_name` should return the output in the form of in the form /[bucket-name]/[object-name]. Could you look for a recently upload file at the bucket name and check if the file is in the bucket and what bucket that is?

Comment: Thanks for pitching in. Unfortunately it is not a recent object. The sorry fact is I store data in the cloud data store, but for some reason and I can even find gs_object_name, but it is no longer there in the bucket. I am diving into my supposed bug where delete of images did not actually deleted them. The fact is the object might even be deleted, and yet, somehow it is still serving

Comment: Could you post the whole piece of code from uploading the image to saving it to saving it in Datastore? Would be interesting to see the whole process.